# Python GUI program in wxPython won't run

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the following code, and I am following a tutorial:

(http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/ - GoToClass part)

I can't figure out what is wrong with it ... :/

As you can see in the tutorial, it is supposed to produce this:

[image]

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# gotoclass.py

import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(390, 350))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
        font.SetPointSize(9)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Class Name')
        st1.SetFont(font)
        hbox1.Add(st1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)
        tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        hbox1.Add(tc, proportion=1)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        vbox.Add((-1, 10))

        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        st2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Matching Classes')
        st2.SetFont(font)
        hbox2.Add(st2)
        vbox.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=10)

        vbox.Add((-1, 10))

        hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        hbox3.Add(tc2, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=1, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND, 
            border=10)

        vbox.Add((-1, 25))

        hbox4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        cb1 = wx.CheckBox(panel, label='Case Sensitive')
        cb1.SetFont(font)
        hbox4.Add(cb1)
        cb2 = wx.CheckBox(panel, label='Nested Classes')
        cb2.SetFont(font)
        hbox4.Add(cb2, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        cb3 = wx.CheckBox(panel, label='Non-Project classes')
        cb3.SetFont(font)
        hbox4.Add(cb3, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        vbox.Add(hbox4, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        vbox.Add((-1, 25))

        hbox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Ok', size=(70, 30))
        hbox5.Add(btn1)
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Close', size=(70, 30))
        hbox5.Add(btn2, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
        vbox.Add(hbox5, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Go To Class')
    app.MainLoop()
```

The following are the errors I'm getting: (Removed the path to the file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]", line 78, in <module>
    Example(None, title='Go To Class')
  File "[path]", line 14, in __init__
    self.InitUI()
  File "[path]", line 21, in InitUI
    font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SystemSettings_GetFont'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(...)`? An error in the example, perhaps ... oops, no, just saw the wxPython note ... you are apparently correct. And yet clearly no such attribute exists in `wx`. Close vote retracted!

Comment: Maybe the docs are out of date - [here](http://nullege.com/codes/search/wx.SystemSettings.GetFont) I see `wx.SystemSettings.GetFont` - give it a try and let us know what happens

Comment: They were indeed out of date - I removed the underscore and added the dot instead. Running it again produces the desired output. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a typo. The correct way is `wx.SystemSettings.GetFont()`, also see the docs: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.SystemSettings.html#wx.SystemSettings.GetFont

Change your `InitUI` method to this:

```
def InitUI(self):
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
    font.SetPointSize(9)
    ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The removal of the '_' version of static methods was removed in wxPython 4.x. See https://docs.wxpython.org/MigrationGuide.html#static-methods

Comment: @RobinDunn thanks for pointing out! So rather taken from an old tutorial or documentation than a typo. Nice to see you around here :)